# Qt:: How to make "snake" game move automatically?

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt to develop a English words snake game. Now I can let it move according to my keypress. But how to let it move according to path I have calculated using A* algorithm?

When Press a key, I set snake's move direction, then use QTimer's timeout() to control snake's movement.

```
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &scene, SLOT(advance()));
```

Now I want to move snake manually without KeyPress Event according to path I have calculated.
But if I call `scene.advance()`, my snake won't move correctly.

```
void GameController::move_snake(int s_x, int s_y, int to_x, int to_y)
{
    if (to_x == s_x) {
        if (to_y > s_y) {
            snake->setMoveDirection(MoveDown);
            scene.advance();
        }
        else {
            snake->setMoveDirection(MoveUp);
            scene.advance();
        }
    }
    else {
        if (to_x > s_x) {
            snake->setMoveDirection(MoveRight);
            scene.advance();
        }
        else {
            snake->setMoveDirection(MoveLeft);
            scene.advance();
        }
    }
}
```

One of my ideas is to use a QEvent Cache, when I calculate a move direction, then construct a QKeyEvent and put it into cache. Does this idea can success? If it can success, how to construct such a cache and QKeyEvent manually ? If not, how to do?

Comment: nice project! I tried it, but can't get the game logic (blackboard is empty, how to fill it ?). Do you have a link to demo the logic ? About your problem, you can construct QKeyEvent(s) and issue them with QCoreApplication::postEvent. I think you already know this...

Comment: In initSceneBackground(), use pixmap to fill background. Thanks for your advice. This is a practice, no good structure, so I don't plan to make a demo. I don't think it's a good project, compared to other projects in Github.

Comment: I have completed that project. It can move automatically now. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: I've downloaded again, but seems less functional now... did you miss to commit map.jpg ?

Comment: Oh, I forget it.  I will upload it now. You should put them in the same directory as your compiled code(executable file).

Comment: thanks. I find easy to use QtCreator resources - just add files to project - it will keep github updated - very handy

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have added them into resources.